# Как изменить регистр введённого символа в строке?

Tags: python

Пример:
Ввод:  Тихо шифером шурша, крыша едет не спеша
для замены буква "ш"
Вывод: Тихо Шифером ШурШа, крыШа едет не спеШа
Пока набил это:

````
s = "Тихо шифером шурша, крыша едет не спеша"
n = input("Введите символ который нужно поднять")
characters = list(s)
s.find(n)
characters = s.upper(n)                                                       
new_text = ''.join(characters)
print(new_text)```
````

Comment: `new_text = new_text.replace(n, n.upper())`

Answer (score 0):

Если n строка

```
def up(text, symbol):
'''
>>>up('abcb','b')
aBcB
'''
   return text.replace(symbol,symbol.upper()
```

Если n номер буквы

```
def up(text,symbol):
'''
>>>up('abc',2)
'aBc'
   return text[:symbol]+text[symbol].upper()+text[symbol:]
```

если n это срез

```
def up(text,symbol):
>>>up('abcdef',(1,3))
'aBCdef'
'''
   return text[:symbol[0]]+text[symbol[0]:symbol[1]]+text[symbol[1]:]
```